# Is it a good idea to build an application fully in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm starting to build my new application and I'm trying to go the right way from the start to make my life easier later in maintaining and extending the application.

I saw applications that are probably built in fragments only. Of course, there is a host activity that hosts the fragments, but everything else is in fragments.

I suppose they have a `Main` activity that has the action bar and a layout to host the content in it. Everything else, including different screens such as Login, Home, Settings, Profile, ... is in fragments.

When we click on an item in the navigation drawer, for example on the Settings button, they simply change the content fragment, instead of launching a new activity for Settings.

Is that a good idea to build the main screens all in fragments, and just have one activity to display them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good idea to split up your UI into Fragments.

Some advantages:
-reuse in multiple Activities
-self-contained, modular UI
-rearrange fragments

Cons:
-it's a bit more work
-slightly higher learning curve

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm already using fragments but my question is if it is good to have just 1 host activity and design all the screens (login, home, settings, ...) In fragments.